# Kadenes Algorithm for maximum product of subarray. Help me find the error in my code

Tags: java

The answer is not expected.Does the for loop creating the error. The max value is not getting updated.I think it should get updated after every iteration but it doesnt seem to.
Array has negative values
contagious subarray

```
class Solution {
public int maxProduct(int[] nums) {
   int gm=nums[0];
    int max=nums[0];
    int min=nums[0];
    int lmax;
    int lmin;
    for(int i=1;i<nums.length;i++){
        max=Math.max(nums[i],Math.max(nums[i]*max,nums[i]*min));
        min=Math.min(nums[i],Math.min(nums[i]*min,nums[i]*max));            
        gm=Math.max(gm,Math.max(min,max));
        
        }
    
     return gm;  
}
```

}

Your input
[2,3,-2,4,-3]
Output
72
Expected
144

Comment: What is the exact expected output for one given sample input?

Comment: Updated the Question for input output Please See

Comment: Why do you expect 144? According to what logic? Certainly not according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm because I guess the correct answer would be `7`

Comment: The product of complete array is 144 which is also a subarray. This product is also the highest therefore

Comment: What is ``lmax`` and ``lmin`` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max=Math.max(nums[i],Math.max(nums[i]*max,nums[i]*min));
min=Math.min(nums[i],Math.min(nums[i]*min,nums[i]*max));
```

Here when calculating `min` you are using the updated value of the `max` in that iteration. But you should use value of previous iteration.

You can calculate max and store in `temp` and after calculating `min` you can update the `max` to fix this.

```
  public int maxProduct(int[] nums) {
    int gm = nums[0];
    int max = nums[0];
    int min = nums[0];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
      int temp = Math.max(nums[i], Math.max(nums[i] * max, nums[i] * min));
      min = Math.min(nums[i], Math.min(nums[i] * min, nums[i] * max));
      max = temp;
      gm = Math.max(gm, Math.max(min, max));
    }
    return gm;
  }
```

Output: `144`

Comment: Yes exactly, Thank you it is such a silly mistake. Actually Two temp will be used. One for min also, and after calculating gm those value will be updated

Comment: Welcome, I just point out the problem and minimal change to fix this. If it solves your problem try to accept the answer.